# Embedded Jetty request content ungzipping

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

How can I enable ungzipping requests content?
I have embedded Jetty server and endpoint receiving POST requests, which have Content-Encoding: gzip. I tried to use GzipHandler, but it seems it only provides response gzipping, not requests ungzipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an up to date version of Jetty and configure GzipHandler for your specific content-types.

It will un(g)zip the request content just fine.

Comment: yeah, updating jetty version helped (but now there is problem with jetty bug concerning gzip handler and async requests, unfortunatelly :( )

Comment: The GzipHandler supports servlet spec AsyncContext and Async I/O just fine.